# Bibliography in blocks in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

Is it possible to write the bibliography in a block in each frame in beamer?
I have used the following code to split the bibliography into frames:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
    \tiny{\bibliographystyle{abbrv} }
    \bibliography{refs}
\end{frame}
```

But what should I do if I want to include the references in each frame inside a single block? Any suggestion please?

Comment: What do you understand by "block"?

Comment: I mean the block environment in beamer presentations ... \begin{block}.....\end{block}

Comment: Do you want to use block environment to change the display of the bibliography ?

Comment: yes thats what I want. In each frame, I want the part of the bibliography to appear in a block environment and it should continue that way to next frames. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not mind using `thebibliography` instead of `\bibliography` you can also use `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}
\tcbset{breakable}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
    \begin{thebibliography}{}

        \begin{tcolorbox}[beamer, skin=beamerfirst, colback=blue!5!white, colframe=blue!50!black, title=Bibliography]

          \bibitem[{Alpher} et~al.(1948) {Alpher}, {Bethe}, \& {Gamow}]{paper}
          Alpher, R. A., Bethe, H. \& Gamow, G. 
          \newblock{The Origin of Chemical Elements}.
          \newblock{\emph{Phys. Rev.}, 73:\penalty0 803--804, Apr. 1948.}
          \newblock{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.803}     

          \bibitem[{Alpher} et~al.(1948) {Alpher}, {Bethe}, \& {Gamow}]{paper2}
          Alpher, R. A., Bethe, H. \& Gamow, G. 
          \newblock{The Origin of Chemical Elements}.
          \newblock{\emph{Phys. Rev.}, 73:\penalty0 803--804, Apr. 1948.}
          \newblock{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.803}

          \bibitem[{Alpher} et~al.(1948) {Alpher}, {Bethe}, \& {Gamow}]{paper3}
          Alpher, R. A., Bethe, H. \& Gamow, G. 
          \newblock{The Origin of Chemical Elements}.
          \newblock{\emph{Phys. Rev.}, 73:\penalty0 803--804, Apr. 1948.}
          \newblock{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.803}

          \newpage

          \bibitem[{Alpher} et~al.(1948) {Alpher}, {Bethe}, \& {Gamow}]{paper4}
          Alpher, R. A., Bethe, H. \& Gamow, G. 
          \newblock{The Origin of Chemical Elements}.
          \newblock{\emph{Phys. Rev.}, 73:\penalty0 803--804, Apr. 1948.}
          \newblock{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.803}

            \end{tcolorbox}

    \end{thebibliography}

        \vfill

    \end{frame} 


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If using the `thebibliography`-environment instead of `\bibliography`, the references can be put insite a `block`-environment quite easily.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
    \begin{thebibliography}{}

        \begin{block}{Bibliographie}

            \bibitem[{Alpher} et~al.(1948) {Alpher}, {Bethe}, \& {Gamow}]{paper}
            Alpher, R. A., Bethe, H. \& Gamow, G. 
            \newblock{The Origin of Chemical Elements}.
            \newblock{\emph{Phys. Rev.}, 73:\penalty0 803--804, Apr. 1948.}
            \newblock{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.803}     

            \bibitem[{Alpher} et~al.(1948) {Alpher}, {Bethe}, \& {Gamow}]{paper2}
            Alpher, R. A., Bethe, H. \& Gamow, G. 
            \newblock{The Origin of Chemical Elements}.
            \newblock{\emph{Phys. Rev.}, 73:\penalty0 803--804, Apr. 1948.}
            \newblock{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.803}

            \bibitem[{Alpher} et~al.(1948) {Alpher}, {Bethe}, \& {Gamow}]{paper3}
            Alpher, R. A., Bethe, H. \& Gamow, G. 
            \newblock{The Origin of Chemical Elements}.
            \newblock{\emph{Phys. Rev.}, 73:\penalty0 803--804, Apr. 1948.}
            \newblock{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.803}

        \end{block} 

        \newpage

        \begin{block}{Bibliographie}    

            \bibitem[{Alpher} et~al.(1948) {Alpher}, {Bethe}, \& {Gamow}]{paper4}
            Alpher, R. A., Bethe, H. \& Gamow, G. 
            \newblock{The Origin of Chemical Elements}.
            \newblock{\emph{Phys. Rev.}, 73:\penalty0 803--804, Apr. 1948.}
            \newblock{http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.73.803}

        \end{block}

    \end{thebibliography}

\end{frame} 


\end{document}
```

[image]