# Bibliography icons are rendered out of the page in Beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies

I am using `beamer` to make a presentation and I noticed that the Bibliography icons are rendered out of the page in Beamer.

See the code below-

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,11pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme{serif}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\tiny}%font size for reference slide
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\tiny}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{\textit{cite} example}
  \begin{itemize}
   \item Saharon et al. \footcite{Saharon1972}
   \item Huo et al. \footcite{Huo2002}
  \end{itemize} 
 \end{frame}

 \begin{frame}{References}
    \printbibliography
 \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Below is the content of bib file-

```
@article{Huo2002,
    author = {Zhimin Huo and Maryellen L. Giger and Olufunmilayo I. Olopade and Dulcy E. Wolverton and Barbara L. Weber and Charles E. Metz and Weiming Zhong and Shelly A. Cummings},
    title = {Computerized Analysis of Digitized Mammograms of BRCA1 and BRCA2 Gene Mutation Carriers},
    journal = {Radiology},
    volume = {225},
    number = {2},
    pages = {519-526},
    year = {2002},
    doi = {10.1148/radiol.2252010845},
    note ={PMID: 12409590},
}
@article{Saharon1972,
author = {Shelah Saharon},
journal = {Annals of Mathematical Logic},
pages = {75--114},
title = {Saturation of ultrapowers and Keisler's order},
volume = {4},
year = {1972},
},
```

Below is the screenshot of the generated PPT-
[image]

Notice that the icons of each reference is printed on the left side of the slide. but unfortunately it is out of the slide.

Comment: Without a .bib file, we cannot compile your MWE.

Comment: @samcarter: Please see the updated question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems the problem is caused by the `infolines` outer theme, which is internally loaded by `Madrid`. The offending command is

```
\setbeamersize{text margin left=1em,text margin right=1em}
```

If you make a local copy of `beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty`, rename it and remove the above line you can use the modified version with `\useoutertheme{bla}`.

Or as a workaround, you could wrap the bibliography into a `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

    \nocite{*}
    \begin{frame}{References}
        \hspace*{0.5cm}
        \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-1cm\relax}
            \printbibliography
        \end{minipage}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Beautiful. Just one question, what if the bib file have many entries? Is `allowframebreaks` gonna work with this approach?

Comment: @RaviJoshi no it won't. But there are other breakable boxes, like `tcolorbox` http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/180440/36296, I you change their colour to the same as the frame background, you won't see them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you mentioned, the whole problem is just because of the `Madrid` theme. May be it is better to avoid it, if things start getting really complicated.

Comment: @RaviJoshi See my edit about an alternative.

Comment: @RaviJoshi For a neat way probably this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/68084/37198